# How can I alter my code so that when I press a button, it is displayed in the entry box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter on Python 3 to make a calculator. I have the layout finished. Now I am trying to get it so that when I press a button, it is displayed in the entry box. For example, if I press the 2 button followed by the + button followed by the 3 button, I want it displayed in the entry box at the top of the program.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class myGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title('Calculator')

        ## Font
        button_font = ('Verdana', 15)
        entry_font = ('Verdana', 36)

        ## Define the frames
        self.frameZero = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameOne = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameTwo = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameThree = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameFour = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameFive = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        ## Define the buttons

        self.my_button1 = tkinter.Button(self.frameOne, text='1', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button1), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button2 = tkinter.Button(self.frameOne, text='2', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button2), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button3 = tkinter.Button(self.frameOne, text='3', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button3), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonadd = tkinter.Button(self.frameOne, text='+', command = lambda:btnClick(my_buttonadd), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button4 = tkinter.Button(self.frameTwo, text='4', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button4), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button5 = tkinter.Button(self.frameTwo, text='5', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button5), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button6 = tkinter.Button(self.frameTwo, text='6', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button6), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonsub = tkinter.Button(self.frameTwo, text='-', command = lambda:btnClick(my_buttonsub), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button7 = tkinter.Button(self.frameThree, text='7', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button7), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button8 = tkinter.Button(self.frameThree, text='8', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button8), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button9 = tkinter.Button(self.frameThree, text='9', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button9), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonmult = tkinter.Button(self.frameThree, text='*', command = lambda:btnClick(my_buttonmult), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonC = tkinter.Button(self.frameFour, text='C', height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button0 = tkinter.Button(self.frameFour, text='0', command = lambda:btnClick(my_button0), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonperiod = tkinter.Button(self.frameFour, text='.', command = lambda:btnClick(my_buttonperiod), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttondiv = tkinter.Button(self.frameFour, text='/', command = lambda:btnClick(my_buttondiv), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttoncalc = tkinter.Button(self.frameFive, text='Calculate', height = 4, width = 30, font = button_font)

        ## Define the entry area
        self.my_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.frameZero, width = 13, font = entry_font)

        ## Pack the entry area
        self.my_entry.pack(side = 'left')

        ## Pack the buttons
        self.my_button1.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button2.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button3.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonadd.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button4.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button5.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button6.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonsub.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button7.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button8.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button9.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonmult.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonC.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button0.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonperiod.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttondiv.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttoncalc.pack(side = 'left')

        ## Pack the frames
        self.frameZero.pack()
        self.frameOne.pack()
        self.frameTwo.pack()
        self.frameThree.pack()
        self.frameFour.pack()
        self.frameFive.pack()

        ## Click button function
        def btnClick(numbers):
            global operator
            operator=operator + str(numbers)
            my_entry = self.set(operator)


        tkinter.mainloop()

my_gui = myGUI()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `tk.StringVar()` that can store the value at the top of the calculator screen. The main methods to know are `.get()` and `.set()` for this variable, that's how you access the value (`.get()`) or update it (`.set()`). You have to link this to the entry with the `textvariable` argument. Once you get that set up, I changed the inputs to your `btnClick()` function to all be strings. Once you have the string you want (for example "12+5") you can use python's built in `eval()` function to compute the result! Note, this method is not safe in that users may execute arbitrary code with it (hack your program) depending on how you implement it! A working version of your code looks like:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class myGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title('Calculator')

        ## Font
        button_font = ('Verdana', 15)
        entry_font = ('Verdana', 36)

        ## Define the frames
        self.frameZero = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameOne = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameTwo = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameThree = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameFour = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frameFive = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        ## Define the entry area
        self.entry_variable = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.my_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.frameZero, textvariable=self.entry_variable, width=13, font=entry_font)

        ## Define the buttons

        self.my_button1 = tkinter.Button(self.frameOne, text='1', command = lambda:btnClick("1"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button2 = tkinter.Button(self.frameOne, text='2', command = lambda:btnClick("2"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button3 = tkinter.Button(self.frameOne, text='3', command = lambda:btnClick("3"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonadd = tkinter.Button(self.frameOne, text='+', command = lambda:btnClick("+"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button4 = tkinter.Button(self.frameTwo, text='4', command = lambda:btnClick("4"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button5 = tkinter.Button(self.frameTwo, text='5', command = lambda:btnClick("5"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button6 = tkinter.Button(self.frameTwo, text='6', command = lambda:btnClick("6"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonsub = tkinter.Button(self.frameTwo, text='-', command = lambda:btnClick("-"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button7 = tkinter.Button(self.frameThree, text='7', command = lambda:btnClick("7"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button8 = tkinter.Button(self.frameThree, text='8', command = lambda:btnClick("8"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button9 = tkinter.Button(self.frameThree, text='9', command = lambda:btnClick("9"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonmult = tkinter.Button(self.frameThree, text='*', command = lambda:btnClick("*"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonC = tkinter.Button(self.frameFour, text='C', height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_button0 = tkinter.Button(self.frameFour, text='0', command = lambda:btnClick("0"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttonperiod = tkinter.Button(self.frameFour, text='.', command = lambda:btnClick("."), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttondiv = tkinter.Button(self.frameFour, text='/', command = lambda:btnClick("/"), height = 3, width = 7, font = button_font)
        self.my_buttoncalc = tkinter.Button(self.frameFive, text='Calculate', height = 4, width = 30, font = button_font, command=self.calculate)



        ## Pack the entry area
        self.my_entry.pack(side = 'left')

        ## Pack the buttons
        self.my_button1.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button2.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button3.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonadd.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button4.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button5.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button6.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonsub.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button7.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button8.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button9.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonmult.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonC.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_button0.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttonperiod.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttondiv.pack(side = 'left')
        self.my_buttoncalc.pack(side = 'left')

        ## Pack the frames
        self.frameZero.pack()
        self.frameOne.pack()
        self.frameTwo.pack()
        self.frameThree.pack()
        self.frameFour.pack()
        self.frameFive.pack()



        ## Click button function
        def btnClick(number_clicked):
            self.entry_variable.set("{}{}".format(self.entry_variable.get(), number_clicked))

    def calculate(self):
        print("{}".format(eval(str(self.entry_variable.get()))))
        self.entry_variable.set("{}".format(str(eval(str(self.entry_variable.get())))))


my_gui = myGUI()
my_gui.main_window.mainloop() # this should NOT be inside your class like you had it...
```

Overall, I liked your frame layout, and overall design. Lambda functions were good too! Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: It could be better if he used `for` loops to create those widgets could've made the job so much easier and it takes lesser space than this.

Comment: @Saad Perhaps. I think that would require restructuring the code significantly though, which I try not to do on here. OP's question was not how to put these into a `for` loop, so to do so would be more work for me and with this few widgets it really isn't a huge deal to me. It's not like thousands or even a hundred widgets are being made, just a dozen or so. OP's question was directly related to implementing a `tk.StringVar()` as I have shown here I would think. If you want to show how to use loops instead, I would encourage you to post a solution that does just that! I would upvote it!

Comment: You're right, it is too much of work I've to make the Gui again as the OP haven't even inherit `Tk()` and it'll be far different from what OP's way which either goes above his head or I've to put a lot of explanation to the answer.